# Програмирование на Windows XP и Windows 98.

Tags: windows-xp

Нашел книгу с программами на языках "Пилот", "Бейсик", "Паскаль", хочу записать их в комп. с Windows XP. Подойдут ли эти программы для Windows 98? На каких языках писать программы для Windows XP и Windows 98.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все зависит от версий программ, которые хотите запустить (хотя в голову не приходят версии, которые идут в 98 но не идут в XP).

Конкретно, Visual Basic 6 у меня спокойно идет под XP. Также консольная версия хорошо запускается и работает. Pascal консольная тоже хорошо идет. (Проблемы у Pascal начинаются в Vista и Win8, возможно и в Win7). Пойдут или нет, вам лучше попробовать, достовернее узнаете.

> На каких языках писать программы для Windows XP и Windows 98

Все зависит от целей. Delphi, C++, C#, и многие другие. У .Net насколько я знаю есть зависимости от сервис пака у XP.